# How do I set this with font size

Tags: c#

On my program a user can send to another user via PM now in the pm you have User1 : msg and then when they send back you have User2:msg return just like on any other messenger.

I believe this line here controls the username as I did not write this and the guy who did wont reply to me even after I paid him.

```
 AddToIMText(this.Receiver + (" : ") + message + Environment.NewLine);
```

I need to make User1 or who ever is sending or receive the message when they reply have it so the size of the username is a little bigger then it is now the guy didn't set no font and I have tried for 5 weeks to get an answer.

Hope someone can help me out.

```
private void AddToIMText(string text)
    {
        if (this.rtb_chat.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(AddToIMText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)

                    Flash(false);
                else
                    Flash(true);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.rtb_chat.Text += text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's inside AddToIMText() function ?

Comment: are you using a rich text box?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information, rather than putting it in a comment.  It will be much easier to read that way.

Comment: Yes I am using a richtextbox

Comment: You'll probably find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17284573/5089204

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another way. I make the font size for the RTB the size I wanted that way it would be better to view then if they want to change the size of their text before sending they can and the username should still be the size I want.

Thanks for all your help.